# Word for "list of lists"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes a list of lists? Does a "masterlist" describe it, or is there something more specific?

Comment: Not sure of a word but, A Collection of lists / Grouped lists.
Or an array of

Comment: Coming from a computer programming background, we use the phrase "nested list" a lot.

Comment: In some cases you could use "matrix".

Comment: Please provide a sentence with a blank where you would use the word. For example, "We drew the fourth form from the second declension in the ______."

Comment: If you use "masterlist" in a programming context, one will understand that some "details lists" will refer to this list. Besides the @rkchl proposol, you may say a "set of lists". "nested lists" is a good expression to encompass all the data including the *parent list* and the *children lists*.

Comment: Thank you for the "nested list" suggestion; it's what I was after.

Comment: Multidimensional list (or matrix like stated above). I'd be tempted to say list list. A list of lists is my list list.

Comment: @BleepBloopOverflow "list list" seems like an appropriate suggestion from a guy named "BleepBloop". Bleep Bloop! List List!

Comment: @CaseyM "a panel of lists"

Comment: Wikipedia has lists of lists and even [lists of lists of lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lists_of_lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set that contains all the members of a smaller set is called a ***superset***.

You might, for the occassion, extend this to lists. A list that contains other lists embedded in it might be called a ***superlist***.